# Should the CLS_LOG be placed before or after the crash? Either way, it won't record the data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I'm using `Crashlytics` and `CLS_LOGS` to send additional information about the crash to `firebase`. The logs are send when I simulate a crash, so things seems to be working.

My dilemma however is that I don't understand how to send the data correctly when the crash occur. If I place the `CLS_LOG` before the crash it won't have the data that is initialized where the app crashes, and if I place the `CLS_LOG` after the crash, the `CLS_LOG` isn't send at all to `firebase`.

To illustrate, here I place the `CLS_LOG` **before** the crash:

```
for(id index in phoneDicts) {
    CLS_LOG(@"phoneDicts:%@", index);
}
//Crashes below
NSArray* phoneDicts = [currentPerson objectForKey:@"phones"];
```

Since the crash occur at the initialization there isn't any data to send to firebase.

And here I place the `CLS_LOG` **after** the crash:

```
//Crashes below
NSArray* phoneDicts = [currentPerson objectForKey:@"phones"];

for(id index in phoneDicts) {
    CLS_LOG(@"phoneDicts:%@", index);
}
```

Here the `CLS_LOG` isn't sent at all since the app crash before it has a chance to send the data.

So, how do I get it to send the data?

Comment: If you can predict the crash, then just fix it :)
You just need to think about which application states you should know, to be able to fix crashes.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I can't predict it really. It happens for a few users a handful of times. I haven't been able to replicate it. I have just thrown in a few nil checks and CLS_LOGS that will hopefully patch things up and add a bit more information.